# How to run an exe present in another directory!

Tags: windows, perl, dos

I want to run an exe from my perl script which is not in the same directory where my perlscript exist. As well as the directory is not in the system PATH. How to set the path in the perl itself and run that exe.
I tried to set env but it didnt work.

thnx,
kas

Comment: I've tagged this as Windows, as you mentioned an "exe" - please feel free to re-tag more appropriately if you're not actually using DOS/Windows. For future reference it's always a good idea to mention what platform/OS/etc you are using and tag accordingly, unless it really is a platform-agnostic question.

Answer (score 3):

Try using the full path to your exe. e.g.

```
system("/full/path/to/app.exe");
```

Did you set your path like this:

To get your PATH:

```
$path = $ENV{'PATH'};
```

To set it:

```
$ENV{'PATH'} = 'some/dir:another/dir';
```

Comment: It is wrong to hard-code `:`. Use [`$Config{path_sep}`](http://p3rl.org/Config) instead.

Comment: @daxim Whilst true, if he's calling some random .exe file, it's not going to be very portable anyway :)

Comment: Reminder: DOS uses `;`, so it's not chiefly about the portability, but about `:` being wrong.

Answer (score 2):

If you know where the exe file is, just use the path to it the same as if you were running it from the command line.  In Perl:

```
system('c:\full\path\to\exe\program.exe');
```

or if you prefer to use forward slashes (they're all the same to the Windows kernel):

```
system('c:/full/path/to/exe/program.exe');
```

Comment: problem is little different here :say exe a.exe is the file which i want to run and a.exe depends on couple of libraries which are on differnt path.Every time i install a.exe those library path also get change.So my intention is to set those path also before i set a.exe path. now wheni say $ENV{PATH}="dependent library path for a.exe":"path of a.exe" it doesn not work when i call system command. As system command spawn a shell and run a.exe.Which does not get all the path i set in the parent before system command. Is ther any way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need to set any environment variables just to run an exe. All you need to do is run the exe using its absolute path or a path relative to the directory you are in when you execute the perl script. For example, assuming this is Windows (since you're talking about an exe) if you have a directory structure like:

```
C:
- dira
| - a.exe
- dirb
  - dirc
    - a.pl
```

and at your command prompt you are running:

```
C:\dirb>perl dirc\a.pl
```

then in your perl file, you should use either

```
`C:\\dira\\a.exe`;
```

or

```
`..\\dira\\a.exe`;
```

If your command prompt is:

```
C:\dirb\dirc>perl a.pl
```

then you can use

```
`C:\\dira\\a.exe`;
```

or

```
`..\\..\\dira\\a.exe`;
```

**Update**

file test.pl:

```
$ENV{'PATH'}.= ':some/dir';
system('./testpath.pl');
```

file testpath.pl:

```
open(FILE, '>>output.txt');
print FILE $ENV{'PATH'};
close(FILE);
```

Comment: Single forward slashes work too as directory seperator and read much nicer than escaped backslashes.

Comment: @daxim, I figured either was ok, but I was too lazy to test it out to be sure ^^.

Comment: problem is little different here :say exe a.exe is the file which i want to run and a.exe depends on couple of libraries which are on differnt path.Every time i install a.exe those library path also get change.So my intention is to set those path also before i set a.exe path. now wheni say $ENV{PATH}="dependent library path for a.exe":"path of a.exe" it doesn not work when i call system command. As system command spawn a shell and run a.exe.Which does not get all the path i set in the parent before system command. Is ther any way to do that?

Comment: @Kaushik, I can't duplicate that. Are you sure the path isn't being passed through? Try making the two perl files I added if you haven't already done something similar.